# Add external Javascript (not jsx) to React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

New React Native user here. I'm trying to add the below Transliterate JS Code from a website to React Native.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Google Transliterate API
  google.load("elements", "1", {
        packages: "transliteration"
      });

  function onLoad() {
    var options = {
        sourceLanguage:
            google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
        destinationLanguage:
            [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.CHINESE],
        shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
        transliterationEnabled: true
    };

    // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
    // options.
    var control =
        new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

    // Enable transliteration in the textbox with id
    // 'transliterateTextarea'.
    control.makeTransliteratable(['transliterateTextarea']);
  }
  google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
</script>
```

Below is the HTML code for the script.

```
<body>
Type in Chinese (Press Ctrl+g to toggle between English and Chinese)<br>
<textarea id="transliterateTextarea" style="width:600px;height:200px"> 
</textarea>
</body>
```

How can I add use this code in React Native? Been struggling with this for weeks. Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to install this library to your react-native project: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/ and use that to access the google API

Answer (score 0):

I would make a Higher Order Component (HOC) that wraps an element with the transliteration. You would use the library that Robbie refers to in the comment to your original question.